# how to calculate |exp(-ia)+exp(-ia')|^2

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the correct way to calculate something like $|\exp(-ia)+\exp(-ia')|^2$ ?
I have tried simply multiplying the term inside the absolute value by its complex conjugate,

$A=(\exp(-ia)+\exp(-ia'))(\exp(ia)+\exp(ia'))=2+\exp(a-a')+\exp(a'-a)$

by this does not seem to be the correct way to do it.

Here $a=ky-\omega t$ and $a'=ky+\pi y-\omega t$. 
According to the book I am using I am supposed to get
$A=(1+\exp(i\pi y))(1+\exp(-i\pi y))$.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Regards,
Newbienewb

Answer (score 1):

if $a=ky-\omega t$ and $b=ky+\pi y-\omega t$, then $a-b=-\pi y$.

$$|\exp(-ia)+\exp(-ib)|^2=2+\exp{(i(a-b))}+\exp{(i(b-a))}=2+2\cos(a-b)$$
$$=2+\cos(\pi y)$$

Answer (score 0):

For any complex number $z=a+ib$, $|z|=\sqrt{z.\bar{z}}$.
Therefore $|z|^2=z.\bar{z}$. For $z=e^{-ia}+e^{-ib}$, $\bar{z}=e^{ia}+e^{ib}$. Then
$z.\bar{z}=e^{-ia+ia}+e^{-ia+ib}+e^{-ib+ia}+e^{-ib+ib}=e^0+e^{-(a-b)i}+e^{(a-b)i}+e^0$
$=2+\cos(a-b)-i\sin(a-b) +\cos(a-b)+i\sin(a-b)=2+2\cos(a-b)$